# Is there a way in TCL to get all actions' info (defined procedures, variables, namespaces, etc.) already performed in the current environment?

Tags: tcl

TCL interpreter knows `info` command, with the options such as `info procs; info locals; info globals;` etc. But in order not to miss something else (for example some package can be defined in the current environment or namespace) I want to get info of performed actions at that time (line of code). The purpose of that I try to reach is to check the state of the environment after using the command `source`. I need to get if there some variable (or other object) is defined that is prohibited for the environment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can maybe create a new interp, save all the initially defined names, use it to run the code, and then compare before and after of the names?

Comment: @Shawn thank you for the comment. It would be better to catch in the same interpreter from software point of view in which I work - creating an interface between a software tool and a soft to hard IP generator.

Comment: If you're worried about anything 'prohibited by the environment' being done by the code you want to evaluate, it's better to sandbox it into its own interp so you can minimize and control the damage.

Comment: If you're using Tcl within Synopsys chip design tools, there's a `history` command that you can use at the command line.   It will print the previous commands (up to a maximum number) in order of use.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know about `namespace children` for listing the namespaces of the current one?

If you really want to know what a `source` command is doing, there's only one possible choice: put an execution step trace on `source`.

```
proc MySimpleTracer {command op} {
    # The $op will always be enterstep because that's what we've attached to
    puts $command
}
trace add execution source enterstep MySimpleTracer
source thefile.tcl
```

That will print everything that the `source` does immediately before it does it. If the code does `load` though, all bets are off; DLLs have access to everything and can't be meaningfully inspected inside with the simple tools that Tcl provides.

---

If the issue is that you don't trust the code, use a safe interpreter. With those, access to the OS is sealed off from the code and you can profile in *with code you control running in your main interpreter* whatever extra privileged operations you want.